# Паттерны программирования

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Не так давно познакомился с MVC. Но на днях появился вопрос: а какие же они еще бывают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Русская Педивикия, статья «Шаблон проектирования»](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Там длиннющая таблица, копировать сюда лень.

Часть паттернов (н-р, синглтон), на самом деле, антипаттерны. В общем, голова на плечах должна быть, иначе эти паттерны могут как следует навредить.

Comment: Кстати да я как то забыл про википедию) Ладно пусть останется для тех кто будет искать)